# Trying to align two horizontal cards together so that the bottom of both images align together

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[Image that has card not fully aligning with one next to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrhq0.jpg) I've been trying to align two horizontal cards so that the bottom of the images align together. This is my current html code:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card w-100 d-flex flex-column">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <div class="card-block">
                <h3 class="header">More Equipment</h3>
                <hr> 
                <p> This is some text and more text and also some more text  </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Read More</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <img class="img-fluid w-100 h-100" src="images/airplane.jpeg" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card w-100 d-flex flex-column">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <div class="card-block">
                <h3 class="header">More Equipment</h3>
                <hr> 
                <p> This is some text and more text and also some more text and more and more
                 </p> 

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Read More</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <img class="img-fluid w-100 h-100" src="images/Agility.jpeg" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>`
```

and my css code:

```
                .card-block {
                  font-size: 1.2em;
                  position: relative;
                  padding: 1em;
                  border-top: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, .1);
                  box-shadow: none;
                }

                .card {
                  font-size: 1em;
                  overflow: hidden;
                  padding: 5;
                  border-radius: .27rem;
                  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #d4d4d5, 0 0 1 1px #d4d4d5;
                  margin-top: 25px;
                }

                .img {
                  object-fit: cover;
                  height: 100%;
                  width: 100%;
                }
```

The current image of what it looks like is posted. My goal is to get the plane to line up with the bottom of the second cards image. I have been using Bootstrap version 4 for this.

I've tried using this code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
              <div class="card-block">
                <h3 class="header">More Equipment</h3>
                  <hr> 
                <p> This is some text and more text and also some more text  </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Read More</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
              <img class="img-fluid d-flex w-100" src="images/airplane.jpeg" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
              <div class="card-block">
                <h3 class="header">More Equipment</h3>
                  <hr> 
                <p> This is some text and more text and also some more text and more and more </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Read More</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
              <img class="img-fluid d-flex w-100" src="images/Agility.jpeg" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The card bottoms are aligned well here, but the image in the first card does not fully go down to the bottom. image: [Plane not lining up to bottom of second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMsK7.jpg)

Comment: What's your Bootstrap version *exactly*?

Comment: [Is that what you want?](https://jsfiddle.net/d9rpb0ho/)

Comment: Bootstrap version is v4.6. Thanks for your answer, but I was looking for the same format I currently have in the second image linked, it's just as you can see in that image the plane image doesn't fully extend to the bottom. I was having an issue getting its width to be the same as the image in the other card (width should be enough to leave no blank space under image). Hopefully what I'm describing makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

adding h-100 to the div class row below the card class was able to solve my issue.